# How to solve linear optimization problems with 1D-array constrain in scipy?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming

I have an optimization problem where one of constrains is: 
(weighted sum of x_i) = constant.

Here is the example:

```
# Solving: ones @ x -> min
# weights 1D-array (n)
ones = np.ones_like(weights)
coefficient = 1/2 * len(weights) * np.prod(weights)
# constrain I want: weights @ x == coefficient
```

`scipy.optimize.linprog` requires 2D-array as coefficients matrix for equality constrain and 1D-array for the right part. But in my case I have 1D-array as coefficients (could easily be converted into diagonal matrix).

We also have coefficient on the right part which we can't convert to vector because there are plenty of variants where the sum is the same but values x_i different, so we can't just constrain all x_i values.

What should you do to solve a problem with such constains?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example when asking a question on this site.

Comment: Just make a 1xn matrix, and use `milp` instead of linprog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. You could create 2D-array for coefficient and 1D-array for right part like that.

```
b_eq = np.zeros_like(weights, dtype=np.float64)
b_eq[0] = coefficient

A_eq_tmp = np.zeros((len(C), len(C)))
A_eq_tmp[0] = weights
```

So basically you fill entire matrix with zeros and same to the right part. Then you fill one row in matrix with your weights and one value in the right part.

Comment: I don't think that this is going to work. OP is looking for a dot product and this isn't one.

Comment: Actually it solved a problem. If we fill all first row in matrix with weights values we will get a dot product at [0] index in a result vector,

Comment: Why is A square? It shouldn't be. And b_eq should only be a one-element vector.

Comment: It has all-zeros except for the first rows. Constrain 0 = 0 is always true.

Comment: Then delete all of the other rows...